# Insert function variable into graph title

Tags: r, graphics, plot

I have a function with two input variables

```
min.depth<-2  
max.depth<-5
```

the function produces a plot. How can I insert the input variables into the title?

I have tried:

```
plot.a<-plot(plt.a$"Traits",plt.a$"Species",xlab="Site similarity by traits (Tsim)",
             ylab="Site similarity by species (Jaccard)",
             main=c("Jaccard vs. Tsim for depths", min.depth, "to",max.depth,"m")
```

While this does insert the input variable correctly it also causes the title to stack as follows:

```
Jaccard vs. Tsim for depths  
2  
to  
5  
m
```

Any ideas on how to avoid this stacking?

Comment: Great work at including example code. Now try to make this reproducible, and I shall take a look. If you can't post your own data, try reproducing your problem with the `iris` data.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use `paste`instead of `c`:

```
plot(..., main=paste("Jaccard vs. Tsim for depths",  min.depth, "to",max.depth,"m", sep=" "))
```

With `c` you create a vector of strings (hence the stacking), with `paste` you concatenate them into one single string.