# How do I dynamically label my ggplot within a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I want the title of each of my plots to be labeled by the contents of my list: "namesvector" instead of just "Scatterplot"

Also bonus question, par(mfrow = c(2,2)) isnt printing all 4 plots side by side, but individually.

```
 par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
namesvector <- list("Start", "Week_1", "Week_3", "Week_5")
for (i in 4:ncol(data_3)) {
  print(
    ggplot(data_3, aes(
      y = data_3[, i], x = Biomass, color = Tissue
    )) +
      geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
      labs(title = "Scatterplot", x = "Biomass", y = "Isotopic Signature")
  )
}
```

Comment: A much better approach would be to turn your data to long using `tidyr::pivot_longer()` than using `facet_wrap()`. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62404983/5221626

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For printing a variable into your title, you need to use paste(), as explained here:

[Inserting function variable into graph title in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206378/inserting-function-variable-into-graph-title-in-r)

Does this help you?

Comment: Hey thank you, any idea how to paste a different name for each plot?
at the moment it gives each plot the title "Start"

Comment: How does it give each plot the title "start"? You don't use the vector "namesvector" creating your plots. I think title = namesvector[i-3] should work with your loop, assuming ncol(data_3) = 7